# Swift JSON decode from URL

Tags: swift

My problem is pretty easy but I can't find solution. I know that there's many of tutorials on how I could do it in other way but I want to keep it simple.

I know how to get data if JSON html looks like this:

```
{"amount":"224.60","currency":"USD"}
```

But I don't know how to get data if it looks like this:

```
"main":{"temp":280.3,"pressure":1023,"humidity":75,"temp_min":280.15,"temp_max":280.37}
```

How to tell that I need to get from "main"?

My code looks like this:

```
struct main: Decodable {
let humidity: String
```

}

```
let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Vilnius,LTU&appid=8a3e3ef324cffc653933f3216efcf80f"
    let urlObj = URL(string: url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data, response, error) in
        do {
            var airs = try JSONDecoder().decode(main.self, from: data!)


            print(airs.humidity)

        } catch {
            print("error")
        }

    }.resume()
```

It works fine with my first example when I'm trying to get amount. But it's not working with my second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let main: Main
}

struct Main: Codable {
    let temp: Double
    let pressure, humidity: Int
    let tempMin, tempMax: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temp, pressure, humidity
        case tempMin = "temp_min"
        case tempMax = "temp_max"
    }
}
```

---

```
var airs = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)
```

OR

```
  do {

    let con = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options: [:]) as! [String:Any]
    let dataCC = con["main"] as! [String:Any] 
    let finData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:dataCC, options: [:])
    let userCon = try JSONDecoder().decode(Main.self, from:finData) 
    print(userCon)

}
catch {

    print(error)
}
```